# On what legal basis do the U.S. troops occupy this Syrian territory?

Tags: united-states, international-law, syria, occupation

The U.S. troops occupy a part of Syria where they have [Al-Tanf](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Tanf) base.

Looking for reasons why is that, I read from the same Wikipedia source:

> U.S. National Security Advisor John Bolton said in early 2019 that
> U.S. operations in the al-Tanf area would continue as a part of the
> U.S. effort to counter "Iranian influence" in Syria

Ok, but is that a valid reason, and does it provide legal justification under international law?